# How to access a pdf from a link thorough axios and send to client from next js api?

Tags: next.js, axios

1. I have created a axios function to call a url to get pdf
2. Now I have to send that PDF as response using Nextjs Framework

   ```
   `@Get('/fileDownload')
     async downloadFiles(@Res() res: Response) {
        const result = await axios.get<Readable>('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'
        );
        const contentType = result.headers['content-type'];
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
        return result.data;
      }`
   ```

I want the pdf file to be sent to my website using nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I added responseType: "stream" in axios config
updated code:

```js
    @Get('/fileDownload')
      async downloadFiles(@Res() res: Response) {
         const result = await axios.get('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf',{
      responseType: 'stream',
    
         );
         const contentType = result.headers['content-type'];
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
         res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
         result.data.pipe(res);
       }
```